# How to install neovim with +clipboard extension?

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard

I have NVIM v0.4.3 installed on Debian 10. When I run:

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

I get `0`, which means that this extension is not available. I cannot copy to OS clipboard using `"+y` and `"*y` commands.

How could I install or make this extension available?

**Update** `:help clipboard` shows:

> **Clipboard integration**
>
> *provider-clipboard clipboard*
>
> Nvim has no direct connection to the system clipboard.
> Instead it depends on a provider which transparently uses shell
> commands to communicate with the   system clipboard or any other
> clipboard "backend".
>
> To ALWAYS use the clipboard for ALL operations
> (instead of interacting with the '+' and/or '*' registers explicitly):
>
> `set clipboard+=unnamedplus`
>
> See 'clipboard' for details and options.
>
> *clipboard-tool*
>
> The presence of a working clipboard tool implicitly
> enables the '+' and '*' registers. Nvim looks for these clipboard
> tools, in order of priority:
>
> - g:clipboard
> - pbcopy, pbpaste (macOS)
> - wl-copy, wl-paste (if $WAYLAND_DISPLAY is set)
> - xclip (if $DISPLAY is set)
> - xsel (if $DISPLAY is set)
> - lemonade (for SSH) https://github.com/pocke/lemonade
> - doitclient (for SSH) [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/doit/](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/doit/)
> - win32yank (Windows)
> - tmux (if $TMUX is set)

Which of these providers could work in Debian Docker container? It seems that only `tmux` is suitable, however I have to start `tmux` session to use it. I have tried `xclip`, but probably `$DISPLAY` is not set in the container and it does not work.

Comment: I have read the clipboard help, but still don't understand how to make clipboard work. My environment is in Docker container, I have installed `xclip`, but still no effect, cannot use +, * registers.

Comment: This problem is really frustrating. Has anybody found a proper solution for this? I am also stuck at this point without any solution

Comment: For NeoVIM 10+ there is a built-in workaround, see: `:h clipboard-osc52`. For older versions these plugins could be used: https://github.com/ojroques/nvim-osc52 and https://github.com/ojroques/vim-oscyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux does not provide any system clipboard. Therefore you can't make use of it.

See, for example, [Access Unix Clipboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/access-unix-clipboard) for explanation.