# Always duplicate yanked text to system clipboard

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, autocmd, os-clipboard

I'm using neovim 0.8.2

Is there a way to automatically mirror last yanked text to system clipboard, regardless of which register I used to yank it to? So if I run something like `"ayiw` I will have it yanked both to `a` register and to `+`?

I was thinking of utilizing `TextYankPost` autocommand to set `let @+ = @...` to the content of last used register, but how do I get the name of the last used register?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could achieve that with:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

More information about `unnamedplus` with `:help unnamedplus`

```
A variant of the "unnamed" flag which uses the
clipboard register '+' (|quoteplus|) instead of
register '*' for all yank, delete, change and put
operations which would normally go to the unnamed
register.  When "unnamed" is also included to the
option, yank operations (but not delete, change or
put) will additionally copy the text into register
'*'.
Only available with the |+X11| feature.
Availability can be checked with: >
    if has('unnamedplus')
```

Comment: Yep! Seems to be working as I expected, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-). If the solution works for you don't forget to validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest ;-)

Comment: Hmm, sorry, looks like it doesn't quite work :) for some strange reason now I get both + and * registered filled correctly but when go to another application and hit ctrl+v I get wrong content

Comment: Even if I explicitly specify `"+yiw` sync between vim and system clipboard seemed to stop working, although it did before. If I don't use `set clipboard=unnamedplus` it does work

Comment: Maybe your system clipboard is `*` and you have to use `set clipboard=unnamed`

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I seem to be able to get what I want with `let @+ = @"` in TextYankPost autocmd, the only downside that it seems to also work on delete/change/etc. Ideally, I'd like it to work only on yank

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled `set clipboard=unnamedplus` should do exactly the same. Every yank, delete or change must update the `+` and `*` register (like your `let @+=@"` does for `+`). For the synchronization to work you need to have a clipboard tool (e.g.: `xclip`) see: [How to install neovim with +clipboard extension?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29285/23502) but i suppose you have that since clipboard integration works without `set clipboard=unnamedplus`

Comment: Correct, I have it working unless I `set clipboard` explicitly. I'm puzzled as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142299/discussion-between-vivian-de-smedt-and-xaxa).

Comment: If this solves your problem maybe could you accept  the solution using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons to make the question rest :-)